# How do I make webpack automatically chunk dynamic imports from node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, code-splitting

I am importing a npm dependency using a dynamic import call like this

```
const { default: Sortable } = await import(
         /* webpackMode: "lazy" */ 'sortablejs'
    );
```

I want webpack to see this import and know to create a separate chunk for it. However webpack seems to keep the dependency in the same main bundle.

This technique works for lazy loading my own js files such as this.

```
const importedComponent = await import(/* webpackMode: "lazy" */ `./components/${templateId}.js`);
```

However for some reason when importing a dependency from node_modules it's not performing this behavior and keeping the dependency bundled within my main bundle.

My webpack config looks like this

```
'use strict';
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = function (env, argv) {
    const webpackConfig = {
        mode: argv.mode,
        devtool: argv.mode == 'production' ? undefined : 'eval',
        target: 'web',
        plugins: [
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        ],
        entry: {
            designer: ['./src/webapps/designer/designer.js', './src/webapps/designer/designer.css'],
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].bundle.js',
            path: path.resolve('build', 'public'),
            publicPath: '/',
            clean: true,
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                url: false,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/i,
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                },
            ],
        },
    };

    return webpackConfig;
};
```

NOTE: I am able to force it to create a separate chunk using optimization.splitChunks.chunks='all';. However this doesn't perform the intended behavior because webpack isn't generating code to dynamically fetch the dependency with a web request. Instead I would have to manually include that chunk in the HTML source code. I want the webpacked code to fetch the dependency on it's own when it is needed.

Node version: 18.0.0

Webpack version: 5.72.0

Webpack cli version: 4.9.2